# How do you git archive a branch using gzip with highest compression level?

Tags: ssh, git, compression, gzip, github

I'm trying to git archive a branch using gzip with the highest level compression (9) but it seems to not compress at that level. Here is my command:

`` git -C /home/user/example.com/ archive --format tar -o /home/user/site_backups/develop-`date +%Y-%m-%dT%H%M`.tar develop | gzip -9 ``

It creates the tar file but the size is over 100MB compared to a zip that was compressed at 86MB using this command:

`` git -C /home/user/example.com/ archive --format zip -o /home/user/site_backups/develop-`date +%Y-%m-%dT%H%M`.zip develop ``

Can the output file be compressed more? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You could use `xz`?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Nice `xz` cuts down the size by ~15MB.